# Ubuntu upgrades break ethernet connection

Tags: updates, lenovo, ethernet, thinkpad

After performing updates on my newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo T440p, the ethernet connection stops working.  I now have no way to connect it to the internet (wi-fi never worked.  I was planning to tackle that next).  How do I find out what's going wrong?

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

dmesg |grep -i eth

```
[    0.979465] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
[    0.979468] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 28:d2:44:bf:b3:3c
[    0.979469] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    0.979498] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: 1000FF-0FF
[    1.451758] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    1.563023] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG_.VID_ handle
[    1.736366] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.484106] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    2.484325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    4.203411] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[    4.203414] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[    4.203442] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:bf:b3:3c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ad2:44ff:febf:b33c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:13978 (13.9 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f1600000-f1620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci` and `dmesg |grep -i eth` right after a fresh boot. Please also post the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: I can't paste the output here.  It's insisting that all USB devices I plug in are read-only, and it won't let me change the permissions

Comment: Look at the output and re-create it here. Help us so we can help you.

Comment: Ok, it will take me a while to type everything

Comment: I ended up booting from liveUSB and then emailing it to myself

Comment: @Jan I just figured out that if I boot into recovery mode, select "network", wait for it to finish connecting and then resume normal startup I can connect to ethernet

Comment: @Jan Please can you help? I've been trying to install Ubuntu for two days.  Now I've found that the nvidia driver doesn't load properly when I boot it in that way.  So I can either use the nvidia driver or connect to the internet, but not both

Comment: Comments aren't instant 'cause I'm in another timezone... I don't know why, but the driver (e1000e) brings up your card with an unusual delay, during which the IP stack tries to configure the interface. I guess this is a driver issue with the e1000e driver. Try to use a newer kernel or get the driver from intel here: http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-032514.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the e1000e driver, it's discussed here:
http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg276476.html

> Just for extended fun: The Thinkpad L440 has the same issue.
>
> 26 Mar 2014: A patch for this issue was submitted into our internal queue on Monday and is in review/testing.

I'm pretty sure that using the [latest driver from intel](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-032514.htm) fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks,  I've found a cleaner workaround (after laptop starts up, restart NetworkManager and nm-applet together).  Considering how hard it was to remove the NVIDIA driver after using the installer on their website, I'm going to avoid trying to install this one.  But thanks anyway.