# eth0 connection fails

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, ethernet, wired

I'm getting really frustrated with Ubuntu 14.04 at this point, after having to solve so many problems with it.

I use my current laptop at work, and there it seems to actually be able to connect over wired network properly. But as soon as I try the same at home, it fails - it doesn't seem to find any connection over eth0, my older laptop (with Ubuntu 12) does just fine with the same cable.

I realized that there are many questions about this issue already, with many similar / different solutions, and before writing this question I already tested many of them whitout success:

Things I tried, in any combination / suggested in other questions as solutions:

I tried `sudo service network-manager restart`, `sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0` and similar commands before and after edits - also rebooting the computer completly several times.

I edited `/etc/network/interfaces`, it currently looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I edited `/etc/resolv.cong` and added `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

I edited `/etc/hosts`

I set `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (then later, back to `managed=false` as it didn't seem to work)

I tried to set a fixed IP according to the MAC of my laptop on my router.

I cannot edit anything over the GUI, all options (Edit connections..., etc) are greyed out.

Edit: Added `ethtool eth0` output as requested. Had to type it down by hand, now the link apparently doesn't work at work either (there was no change on my side, the laptop was shut down during the night, and it worked yesterday at work - now, I don't have any connection at all).

Edit 2: Added lscpi output

---

Now, here the `/var/log/syslog` and the `ifconfig` after a `sudo service network-manager restart`:

```
root@laptop:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:bf:ab:ed  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ad2:44ff:febf:abed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:33030 (33.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f1600000-f1620000 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:bf:ab:ed  
          inet addr:169.254.11.229  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f1600000-f1620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11488 (11.4 KB)  TX bytes:11488 (11.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:b2:bd:92:d6:fa  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

```
root@laptop:~# tail /var/log/syslog -f
Oct 18 20:45:26 laptop avahi-autoipd(eth0)[2930]: Successfully called chroot().
Oct 18 20:45:26 laptop avahi-autoipd(eth0)[2930]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Oct 18 20:45:26 laptop avahi-autoipd(eth0)[2930]: Starting with address 169.254.11.229
Oct 18 20:45:33 laptop avahi-autoipd(eth0)[2930]: Callout BIND, address 169.254.11.229 on interface eth0
Oct 18 20:45:33 laptop avahi-daemon[789]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.11.229.
Oct 18 20:45:33 laptop avahi-daemon[789]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 18 20:45:33 laptop avahi-daemon[789]: Registering new address record for 169.254.11.229 on eth0.IPv4.
Oct 18 20:45:37 laptop avahi-autoipd(eth0)[2930]: Successfully claimed IP address 169.254.11.229
Oct 18 20:46:07 laptop ntpdate[2997]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Oct 18 20:46:07 laptop ntpdate[2997]: no servers can be used, exiting
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/katai is already mounted
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[2851]: <info> caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[2851]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [30 10 36]
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[2851]: <info> (wlan0): cleaning up...
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[2851]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[2851]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[2851]: <info> exiting (success)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop kernel: [  733.342547] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop ModemManager[2823]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop ModemManager[2823]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop ModemManager[3092]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.0.0) starting...
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> NetworkManager (version 0.9.8.8) is starting...
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Read config file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> WEXT support is enabled
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> DNS: loaded plugin dnsmasq
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPluginIfupdown: guessed connection type (eth0) = 802-3-ethernet
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_connection_setting_from_if_block: name:eth0, type:802-3-ethernet, id:Ifupdown (eth0), uuid: 681b428f-beaf-8932-dce4-687ed5bae28e
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: adding eth0 to connections
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: adding iface eth0 to eni_ifaces
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: autoconnect
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPluginIfupdown: locking wired connection setting
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/net/wlan0, iface: wlan0)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/net/wlan0, iface: wlan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ofono: Acquired D-Bus service com.canonical.NMOfono
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ofono: init!
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ofono: end _init.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Loaded plugin (null): (null)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 1
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (34219568) ... get_connections.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (34219568) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ofono: (34004416) ... get_connections.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    SCPlugin-Ofono: (34004416) connections count: 0
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 1
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-12) Object not found
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (eth0): carrier is ON
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'e1000e' ifindex: 2)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'iwlwifi' ifindex: 3)
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop kernel: [  733.397446] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
Oct 18 20:47:12 laptop kernel: [  733.397698] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): preparing device.
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop kernel: [  733.409840] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop kernel: [  733.410134] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> urfkill disappeared from the bus
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: message repeated 2 times: [ <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)]
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0) supports 5 scan SSIDs
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> ModemManager available in the bus
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
Oct 18 20:47:13 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0) supports 5 scan SSIDs
Oct 18 20:47:15 laptop ModemManager[3092]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0': not supported by any plugin
Oct 18 20:47:15 laptop ModemManager[3092]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Oct 18 20:47:16 laptop NetworkManager[3098]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

---

```
#root@laptop:~$ ethtool eth0
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 2
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: off (auto)
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                       drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

---

```
root@laptop:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

Comment: Tell me the output of `sudo ethtool eth0`. The command `ethtool` is in the package `ethtool`, if not installed.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Hm, but how can I install something if I don't have access to the internet? I could try when I'm back at work (if I didn't ruin it for work too, now), but that will take another day, since I won't be there until monday

Comment: It is probably installed by default. I mentioned it just to make sure.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Sorry that it took me so long, but this week was a bit stressy. It doesn't work at work anymore either, but just since today (yesterday it worked fine, at least at work) - with no further changes on my side (the laptop was shut down during the night). This could mean it has something to do with the router configuration? But to my knowledge, nothing was changed at our working place (I asked our network administrator) - and besides, even if something changed I'ld think my system should be able to handle it. I hope you can help me out, I can't do any work atm!

Comment: Couple of notes: 1. If you mention an interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, then Network Manager will ignore that interface unless `managed=true` is set. 2. Changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` are lost on reboot. That said, if you run `dhclient eth0`, do you get an IP? What model is your LAN card (use `lspci`)?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior After trying around (didn't have much of a choice) and retrying everything I tried at home, the `service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0` command worked at work, while all other service-restart attempts (`service network-manager restart`) failed. I know that the command doesn't work at home (takes infinite time), and I guess always having to type that command isn't a solution either... at least I can use my laptop at work for the moment, but who knows what happens with the next restart.

Comment: @muru I tried `managed=true` but the only thing that happens is that he infinitely tries to connect, while the "you are not connected" message pops up every second. Added `lspci` output for you.

Comment: Looks like you have the same Ethernet adapter:

[I217-LM problem][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/522967/ubuntu-upgrades-break-ethernet-connection

Comment: This might help since you have the same Ethernet adapter:


[Ethernet adaper problem][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/522967/ubuntu-upgrades-break-ethernet-connection

Comment: @ajaaskel I'll try it out, will be able to give feedback during the weekend when I'm back home, but if that works it'ld be perfect. So much for "certified" for Ubuntu (Lenovo T440p) ;)

Comment: As a few mentioned the `/etc/resolv.conf` would be overwritten by system. Run the command `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` and look at this file ⇒ there should appear a few lines like `nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx` *(the `sudo ifup eth0`starts an interface, and then trying to get own IP and IP of a DNS servers from a dhcp-server if the interface mentioned like `iface eth0 inet dhcp` in the `/etc/network/interfaces`)*. If it doesn't, post here a log of the command I just mentioned. And in any way comment here what happened.